# 500 Internal Server Error con Socialite Google al llamar a user()

Tags: laravel-5, google-apps-script

Me rompe la conexión en la linea:

```
$user = Socialite::driver('google')->user();
```

Todas las configuraciones son correctas ya que en mi servidor XAMPP local funciona a la perfección; pero ahorita lo estoy migrando a mi server y me regresa error en esa parte.

Ayer funcionó una vez pero ya no quiere, cuando redirecciona me manda error 500 Internal Server Error.

Si le pongo un `try` me lo bota.

Comment: El error 500 tiene muchas causas posibles, ¿tienes acceso a los logs del servidor para obtener más información?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Debes siempre desarrollar mirando los logs para tener todo controlado en caso de falla. Las fallas 500 por lo general es un error antes o durante la ejecución de Laravel, que no llegan al log del framework, por lo que si lo estás mirando, no verás el fallo.

Sugerencia, revisa siempre en este orden:

1) access.log de apache, para saber si ingresó a tu servidor web, con qué parámetros, si haciendo POST o GET, etc.

2) error.log de apache, ahí verás el fallo a nivel del servidor web, muchas veces verás un error ahí y no llegará a verse en el log de laravel.

3) php_errors.log, si tienes configurado para enviar los errores desde tu php.ini

4) proyecto/storage/logs/laravel.log, el log de tu proyecto que genera Laravel.

Revisa estos caminos y verás el error concreto donde está fallando por 500

Comment: Muchas gracias, no tenía acceso al log de apache, y laravel no me mostraba errores, cambie las configraciones del log de laravel y me mostro los errores, entre otras cosas corespondia a perimsos de carpetas, gracias por su ayuda